# Do I need to set heightForRowAtIndexPath if I am using a custom UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, interface-builder

Do I need to set heightForRowAtIndexPath if I am using a custom UITableViewCell? In my NIB I have already set the cell height.

When I over-ride heightForRowAtIndexPath the contents of my cell don't appear, even though it is set to the height defined in the NIB.

If I don't over-ride heightForRowAtIndexPath the contents of the cell appear, but there is overflow since the default height is not large enough.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If all your rows are the same height, then you can set the `rowHeight` property of your `UITableView` instead of implementing `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.  If you have rows of different heights, then you have to implement `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Neither of these methods will automatically return the height of the cell you defined in your NIB, as they get called before you start constructing cells in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

To use the height of the cell defined in your NIB, I recommend that you define a custom property of your controller called `prototypeCell`, which will hold a single cell that never gets displayed on your table.  In `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`, check to see if `prototypeCell` is nil.  If it is, initialize it from your NIB.  Then return `prototypeCell.frame.size.height`.

Comment: How are you initializing the prototypeCell? Are you using  `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:`? If I use that, then `prototypeCell.frame.size.height` returns the default height (44) and not the height defined in the xib.

Comment: The nib load can initialize it for you, and will include the correct height. You can register a nib for the cell, or map a prototype cell to an IBOutlet in your controller's xib.