# Is there a shortcut to accessing a xib's initial attributes?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I do a lot of animations with UIKit and I frequently store any animated view's initial frames in `viewDidLoad` to always have a reference to the frame as it appears in a xib.

This is kind of smelly and seems like the kind of thing that would be automated, but I can't seem to find any info on this. Is there a property on UIView that stores initial xib frame sizes? Or maybe a UIKit utility method that scans the xml of a xib for it's attribute values by name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So while I could not find any way to access an interface builder file's initial attributes (unless you count writing an IB XML parser a *way*), I found a brilliant alternative from [Do I need to set heightForRowAtIndexPath if I am using a custom UITableViewCell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999580/do-i-need-to-set-heightforrowatindexpath-if-i-am-using-a-custom-uitableviewcell/3000401#3000401). Instead of accessing some constant values from an object itself (I was hoping for a `self.attribute.nib.value`), you can make two outlets per IB object- one for manipulating, and one for a prototype- which will hold all the original values of the xib.

To makes things simple, just create an(other) outlet for your nib and override its getter.
For example, if we have a `LargeCell.xib`, we would create an outlet for `largeCell` and another for `largeCellPrototype`.

Then we would make a lazy accessor for this prototype to ensure the prototype is not nil and only loaded once.

```
- (LargeCell*)largeCellPrototype
{
    if (!_largeCellPrototype)
    {                         
       [NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([LargeCell class]) // Presuming you don't name files with reckless abandon
                                    owner:self
                                  options:nil];
    }
}
```

now getting the initial values is as simple as

```
CGFloat initialViewHeight = self.largeCellPrototype.frame.size.height;
```