# How to set custom TableViewCells heightForRowAtIndexPath w.r.t some contents

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

I have a scenario. I have 5 custom UITableViewCells with different contents. First one have an UIImageView and a View, containing some UILabels and other cells are different with each one as well. I want UIImageView width resized to the phone screen width & the height depends on the ratio of the image, while this cell have another UIView which has some labels, and its size is fixed. So my question is How should I calculate heightForRowAtIndexPath for the discussed cell.

Comment: Note that there may be different sized images for the said cell so no fixed hight can be set. Also I have designed these cells using xib.

Comment: Though I have found a solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999580/do-i-need-to-set-heightforrowatindexpath-if-i-am-using-a-custom-uitableviewcell but it is difficult for me to understand and implement.